# WebAssembly exported function returns undefined

Tags: webassembly

I am trying to run [wasm-flate](https://github.com/drbh/wasm-flate) on a WebWorker thread for my javascript application.

Using:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wasm-flate@0.1.11-alpha/dist/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Works fine for getting the flate object into the main thread, but to get it working on a WebWorker, I used

```
wapm install drbh/flate
```

and then took the compiled .wasm code, and am trying to load it on the WebWorker with:

```
fetch("../lib/wasm_flate_bg.wasm")
.then(function(response){
    response.arrayBuffer()
        .then(function(buffer){
            WebAssembly.compile(buffer)
            .then(function(obj){
                WebAssembly.instantiate(obj)
                    .then(function(skee){
                        flate=skee;
                        console.log(flate);
                        console.log(flate.exports);
                        console.log(flate.exports.zlib_encode);
                        console.log(flate.exports.zlib_encode('420'));
                    });
            });
        });
});
```

This all works, up to the point I actually run the zlib_encode function. For some reason it always returns undefined, all of the functions seem to. However, they work fine when loaded through the .HTML.

So, my question is, what am I misunderstanding here and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAssembly functions operate on numbers only. For a high-level level interface like `zlib_encode()` you need a wrapper function in JavaScript that interfaces with the low-level definitions the WebAssembly module exports.

In the case of wasm-flate these seem to be provided by https://unpkg.com/wasm-flate@0.1.11-alpha/dist/0.bootstrap.js, and defined in https://github.com/drbh/wasm-flate/blob/master/src/lib.rs.

Comment: Exactly right, thanks again for your help. This is invaluable information on my journey to understanding WebAssembly better.